# Is “dégoter” in the sense of “essayer de trouver” only used in Switzerland?

Tags: vocabulaire, régionalismes, suisse

I just said in conversation:

> Ils ne vont pas tarder à rappliquer, remarque. Contente-toi de nous **dégoter** un bon petit restau pour ce soir !

... and my colleague pointed out that he might just as well have phrased the sentence as:

> Contente-toi d'**essayer** **de** nous **dégoter** un bon petit restau pour ce soir !

I checked this up on Wiktionnaire, and it indeed says that this particular usage of "dégoter" in the sense of "essayer de trouver", not just "trouver", is only seen in Switzerland.

I find myself dropping "essayer" when using "dégoter" like this, but I wonder how native French speakers from France, Canada, and Belgium commonly phrase this?

---

Now that I think about it, when I use "dégoter" in the following context, for instance, the idea of "essayer" is not included; merely the idea of "having found it by chance".

> Elle a eu la gentillesse de nous **dégoter** une bouteille de Beaujolais Nouveau.

Comment: I don't understand the question. In “Contente-toi de nous dégoter un bon petit restau pour ce soir !”, *dégoter* means “find”, not “try to find”. This is an exhortation to succeed, not just to make an attempt. “Just make sure and find a nice restaurant for tonight.”

Comment: L'[article](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9goter) au Wiktionnaire est tout simplement bizarre. On dit que dégoter voudrait dire au Québec _tenter de trouver un emploi_ avec un exemple contenant le bout de phrase _dans l’espoir de dégoter un boulot_ !! L'article Wiktionnaire témoigne à mon avis d'une lecture douteuse de l'entrée au DHLF qui mentionne le jeu et le sens de trouver un poste en supplantant qqn. comme origines des sens déplacer et dénicher/trouver d'aujourd'hui. Voir aussi [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9goter). Merci !

Answer (score 2):

As a native French speaker from France I will give you some insight about how we use "dégoter" here.

As everything else in French, it's again a matter of context.

"Il est sorti en boîte de nuit, il s'est dégoté une fille pour la soirée" - "He went to a night club and found a girl for the night"

Here dégoter gives the idea of trials and errors. The girl he found was likely not his first choice and also express a slight idea of randomness behind finding the girl.

Whereas in "Il nous a dégoter un petit resto" - "He found us a little restaurant"

Here it somewhat expresses the idea of expertise. Dégoter means finding a secret gem.

But I can confirm that French people do use dégoter. It's use by people liking the precision of language as well as by everyday people that naturally have a thing to use typical expressive French.

Comment: I just realize, that I have absolutely not answered the initial question. I got carried away by my explanation haha

Answer (score 2):

"Dégoter" comes from a game where it was the use to shout :"Dégot s'en va !" when the player was trying to score, so basically, dégoter used to mean "to give it a try" while playing to this game.

I'm sure in France and Belgium no native speaker will ever understand "dégoter" as in Switzerland.

In Canada however, I wouldn't be surprised, many french words in Canada and Switzerland are closer to their etymology than they are in France.

Comment: Being a French-Canadian, I will say that my understanding of *‘dégoter’* is not the one you describe here. I find this usage very interesting, though. Unfortunately, Switzerland & Canada a apart on this one, as far as I’m concerned...

Comment: I can confirm from Belgium too (where we often have common archaic usages with Swiss French, though): same meaning here as "to find something that was unexpected or hard to find", not "try to find". But as the 2 meanings are quite close, I expect this would cause no actual misunderstandings, just maybe a bit of surprise.